# After Effects: How to use Depth Matte if you have color and depth in different files?

Tags: after-effects

I want to use the Depth Matte effect: https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/after-effects/using/3d-channel-effects.html

but it seems these assume the sequence was loaded from a file that contains both color and depth in the same file.

I have a color pass as exr file as well as a depth pass as exr file. How can I combine these two in After Effects so that I can use the Depth Matte effect (basically I want the opposite of what the "3D Channel Extract" effect does - instead of extracting a 3D channel, I want to inject one)?